# EF is dropping tables during migration : "Can't DROP 'Issue'; check that column/key exists"

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am performing migrations of database and the migrations consistently drop the "Issue" column although it's been specifically added in the code.

Code for migration:

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
        name: "ticket",
        columns: table => new
        {
            Id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
            IssueCategoryId = table.Column<long>(type: "bigint", nullable: true),
            Issue = table.Column<string>(type: "varchar(95)", maxLength: 95, nullable: true),
            AssignedTo = table.Column<string>(type: "varchar(95)", maxLength: 95, nullable: true),
            DateCreated = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "datetime", nullable: true),
            DateResolved = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: true),
                            
            Solved = table.Column<bool>(type: "tinyint(1)", nullable: false),
            UserId = table.Column<string>(type: "varchar(95)", maxLength: 95, nullable: true)
        },
        constraints: table =>
        {
            table.PrimaryKey("PK_Tickets", x => x.Id);
            table.ForeignKey(
                name: "FK_ticket_aspnetusers_userid",
                column: x => x.UserId,
                principalTable: "aspnetusers",
                principalColumn: "Id",
                onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
            table.ForeignKey(
                name: "FK_ticket_assigned_aspnetusers_userid",
                column: x => x.AssignedTo,
                principalTable: "aspnetusers",
                principalColumn: "Id",
                onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
            table.ForeignKey(
                name: "FK_ticket_issue_category_issue_category_id",
                column: x => x.IssueCategoryId,
                principalTable: "issue_category",
                principalColumn: "Id",
                onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
        });
```

Code in DbContext :

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Ticket>(entity =>
    {
        entity
            .HasKey(e => e.Id).HasName("PRIMARY");
            entity.ToTable("ticket");

        entity.HasIndex(e => e.IssueCategoryId, "IssueCategoryId");

        entity.Property(e => e.AssignedTo)
            .HasMaxLength(95)
            .HasColumnName("AssignedTo");
        entity.Property(e => e.DateCreated)
            .HasDefaultValueSql("'NULL'")
            .HasColumnType("datetime")
            .HasColumnName("DateCreated");
        entity.Property(e => e.DateResolved)
            .HasDefaultValueSql("'NULL'")
            .HasColumnType("int(11)")
            .HasColumnName("DateResolved");
        entity.Property(e => e.Id)
            .HasColumnType("int(11)")
            .HasColumnName("Id");
        entity.Property(e => e.Issue)
       .HasMaxLength(255) // Adjust the maximum length as needed
       .HasColumnName("Issue");
       
        entity.Property(e => e.IssueCategoryId)
            .HasColumnType("bigint(20)")
            .HasColumnName("IssueCategoryId");
        entity.Property(e => e.Solved).HasColumnName("Solved");
        entity.Property(e => e.UserId)
            .HasMaxLength(95)
            .HasColumnName("UserId");

        entity.HasOne(d => d.IssueCategory).WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.IssueCategoryId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)
            .HasConstraintName("IssueCategoryId");

        entity.HasOne(t => t.AssignedToNavigation)
          .WithMany(u => u.TicketAssignedToNavigations)
          .HasForeignKey(t => t.AssignedTo)
          .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
    });
```

Ticket.cs :

```
public partial class Ticket
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public long? IssueCategoryId { get; set; }

    public string? Issue { get; set; }
   
    public string? AssignedTo { get; set; }

    public DateTime? DateCreated { get; set; }

    public int? DateResolved { get; set; }

    public bool Solved { get; set; }

    public string? UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual Aspnetuser? AssignedToNavigation { get; set; }

    public virtual IssueCategory? IssueCategory { get; set; }

    public virtual Aspnetuser? User { get; set; }
}
```

Every migration drops the column and raises the "Can't DROP 'Issue'; check that column/key exists".

Edit: after Update-Database command. the migration file looks like this:

```
public partial class dbtes : Migration
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
            name: "Issue",
            table: "ticket",
            type: "varchar(95)",
            maxLength: 95,
            nullable: true,
            oldClrType: typeof(string),
            oldType: "varchar(255)",
            oldMaxLength: 255,
            oldNullable: true)
            .Annotation("MySql:CharSet", "utf8mb4")
            .OldAnnotation("MySql:CharSet", "utf8mb4");
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
            name: "Issue",
            table: "ticket",
            type: "varchar(255)",
            maxLength: 255,
            nullable: true,
            oldClrType: typeof(string),
            oldType: "varchar(95)",
            oldMaxLength: 95,
            oldNullable: true)
            .Annotation("MySql:CharSet", "utf8mb4")
            .OldAnnotation("MySql:CharSet", "utf8mb4");
    }
```

Comment: Just to be clear what are the steps you used to migrate?

Comment: Add-Migration migrationName and then update-database

Comment: Your code has different lengths for the Issue column, this could be causing EF to hiccup.
Issue = table.Column<string>(type: "varchar(95)", maxLength: 95, nullable: true),

entity.Property(e => e.Issue)
.HasMaxLength(255) // Adjust the maximum length as needed
.HasColumnName("Issue");

Comment: old migration name : mig1, new migration name : mig2.  I ran the command 'update-database mig1` since that's the migration with everything defined. then `add-migration mig2' 'update-database mig2`. but it still throws the same error. "Can't DROP 'Issue'; check that column/key exists"

Comment: the Up method of mig2 now looks like : `
            migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
                name: "Issue",
                table: "ticket",
                type: "varchar(95)",
                maxLength: 95,
                nullable: true,
                oldClrType: typeof(string),
                oldType: "varchar(255)",
                oldMaxLength: 255,
                oldNullable: true)
                .Annotation("MySql:CharSet", "utf8mb4")
                .OldAnnotation("MySql:CharSet", "utf8mb4");
        `

Comment: If this happens on update-database can you share the generated migration file?

Comment: this is what was generated by after adding a new migration. I edited the dbcontext to reflect the length properly. `  entity.Property(e => e.Issue)
           .HasMaxLength(95) // Adjust the maximum length as needed
           .HasColumnName("Issue");`